# Auto-play not working - CD-ROMS and USB drive

Tags: windows-xp, windows-registry, autorun, autoplay, usb-storage

No help from Google or Microsoft - so I'll ask some experts.  All solutions I have tried are below.

When I put a CD in the computer, or plug in a USB flash drive, I don't get a window asking me what I want to do (play music, open folder to view files, nothing, etc.) I tested the USB drive on my other computer, and I get the dialog.

The devices show up in My Computer.  If I right click and select properties, auto-play is enabled for all file types.

Microsoft suggestions tried: http ://support.microsoft.com/kb/330135
1. Roxio Easy CD Creator is not installed.
2. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\CDRom Autorun = 1
3. HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer NoDriveTypeAutoRun = 91
4. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon allocatecdroms = 0
5. The ASUS DRW-014L1T cd/dvd drive has the latest drivers, and is compatible with XP.

Microsoft autoplay repair wizard: http ://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=c680a7b6-e8fa-45c4-a171-1b389cfacdad&displaylang=en#Instructions
1. Downloaded and ran autofix - if reported a repair, and said to reboot. No change. Ran tool again, now it says it already ran, and I need to log on/off before running it again. I logged off/on and also rebooted several times, and I still get this message.
THIS TOOL IS BUGGY!

Googled suggestions not redundant with the above -

The Microsoft tool APPMDiag is supposed to do a postmortem report on it's last autoplay when you remove a device - nothing appears in the window when I take out a USB flash drive or a music CD.

Running gpedit.msc (to open the Group Policy window) :
1. Local computer policy - User configuration - Administrative templates - System - Turn off autoplay = disabled
2. Local computer policy - Computer configuration - Administrative templates - System - Turn off autoplay = disabled

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can suggest is that you try PowerToys TweakUI from http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/downloads/powertoys/xppowertoys.mspx. In the My Computer -> AutoPlay section there are numerous options, some of which no doubt use the same registry keys as you have mentioned. If that doesn't work then I guess there must be something wrong with your XP installation.

Comment: I got that working for my USB drive.  The CD still won't autoplay.  I'm not spending more time on this.