# How to re-enable Autoplay for removeable drives on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, autoplay

When I plug a USB thumb drive into my Win7 PC, it no longer auto-launches the window giving me options like "Import Photos" or "browse". The drive is recognized but nothing autolaunches.

Similarly, CD's don't autoplay either.

I verified that Win7 is set to autoplay, per method 1 and 2 of:
http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/27544-autoplay-enable-disable-autorun.html

FYI, there is a [similar question (but for Windows XP)](https://superuser.com/questions/168917/auto-play-not-working-cd-roms-and-usb-drive) here on SU.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but are you sure you have checked under "AutoPlay" the options "Use AutoPlay for all media and devices", and also set all items to "Ask me every time"? How about clicking the "Reset All Defaults" button at the bottom and then restarting?

Comment: On a side note having Autoplay disabled is not a bad idea. The DoD was plagued by the Conficker worm which exploits the Autoplay feature on Windows. http://www.stripes.com/news/dod-on-high-alert-for-conficker-worm-1.89829

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[solution summarized from another website](http://www.sevenforums.com/hardware-devices/124826-trying-enable-autorun.html) (wanted to note it before I reboot and try):

In the following Registry Key:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
and possibly (but not needed in my case) in:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer

The value:

> "NoDriveTypeAutoRun" set as 0x000000FF
>   (255) which I have found out disables
>   Autorun on every device.

Set this value to decimel 145 (the default).

Other value (I've not confirmed they are correct)

0x1 Disables AutoPlay on drives of unknown type.
0x4 Disables AutoPlay on removable drives.
0x8 Disables AutoPlay on fixed drives.
0x10 Disables AutoPlay on network drives.
0x20 Disables AutoPlay on CD-ROM drives.
0x40 Disables AutoPlay on RAM drives.
0x80 Disables AutoPlay on drives of unknown type.

0xFF Disables AutoPlay on all types of drives.

Comment: just delete the entire key

Comment: When I renamed the Value and rebooted, my PC wouldn't start (it did a System Restore to reset that value).  I'm *guessiing* that deleting the key would have the same (bad) effect.

Answer (score 0):

The link to seven forums should sort the problem out.
However, if your computer is part of a domain this may be restricted by group policy.
It could also be disabled by your antivirus.

Can you try running it with your antivirus disabled (could be risky unless you know USB drive is clean).
Can you confirm whether you are part of a domain?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to disable autoplay is by using [Autoplay Disabler Pro](http://www.autoplaydisabler.us). I use it, it's cool app really.

Comment: Just to note that the site this is linked to is down